# Why am I not getting the full text of this page?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape the pip install guide [webpage](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) for the [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) script links. When I find those links, I use BeautifulSoup's get_text() to get all of the text.

Now, this works for the get-pip.py link but not for the ez_setup.py link. I retrieve all of the text for get-pip.py but for ez_setup.py I only retrieve text up to the 318th line which isn't even the complete 318th line.

```
317    if options.user_install:
318        if sys.version_info
```

Here is my code.

```
#imports

def makeSoup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

url = "http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html"
for url in makeSoup(url).find_all('a', attrs = {'href':re.compile(r'py$')}):
    with open(desktop + "\\" + url['href'].split('/')[-1], "w", 0) as file:
        file.write(makeSoup(url['href']).get_text())
```

How can I retrieve all of the text for ez_setup.py?

Comment: Oh, go on and put the full list of imports in there. It's only, what, three extra lines? :)

Comment: Why are you wrapping a Python script in Beautiful Soup and then calling `get_text` on it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to parse Python source code as HTML, and then strip the text back out of it.

So, line 318 is:

```
    if sys.version_info < (2, 6):
```

This happens to be the first `<` character in the file. Since you're trying to parse it as HTML, that means that the whole rest of the file is part of an HTML tag that never gets finished.

Depending on which of the three parsers you use, and which versions, bs4 may decide it's not a tag after all and give you your original data, or raise an exception, or strip out the whole bogus tag.

Anyway, the fix is simple: Don't parse Python source code as HTML. Just write this:

```
urllib2.urlopen(url['href']).read()
```

Comment: Ok, now the part about the `<` was something I didn't consider. That makes sense. What doesn't make sense is that my first attempt at getting the scripts was through urllib2 just exactly as you have it. However, when I ran the scripts with `os.system("python " + file.name)` right after writing within the context manager, I would get `EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal`. Thus the use of BeautifulSoup. Well, I run them now and I don't get the error.

Comment: @KrimCard: I don't understand why you thought that parsing the script as HTML and then converting it back to text might help. Just throwing random things at the problem in hopes they might help is rarely a good idea. Look at the text you've downloaded and see what went wrong, and then you can figure out how to fix it (or ask someone, e.g., on SO).

Comment: @KrimCard: As a side note, you almost never want to use `os.system`, as the docs for that function say. Look at the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for a better option that's just as easy and has none of the problems.